# Apache Camel - How to Handle unsuccessful message routing between one endpoint to another?

Tags: java, apache, apache-camel

Currently I am facing a scenario in which if routing of message between one endpoint to another is fail or unsuccessful then it hit a particular java class.

How should I achieve this? Is a there any inbuilt API or method in Apache camel for the same?

Comment: it would be better if you put your existing route and explain your desired outcome. There are many ways to handle exceptions in apache-camel

Comment: Read about error handling in Camel - As there are many things that can go wrong and people have different uses-cases and requirements how to deal with that, then Camels error handling is very flexible but comes with a cost of taking time to learn and master. Your question here on SO is very generic and open ended. Study the other Camel examples and consider pickup one of the Camel books to really learn it better/more.

Comment: i have a situation in which i want to know that message is successfully delivered from one exchange to other, i.e i want to acknowledge my producer that it successfully send message to consumer. In my route chain file there are multiple exchanges (producer1-consumer1)--------(producer2-consumer2) i want some thing which tell my consumer1 that its successfully delivered message to producer2.